# No CSS como faço para alinhar os Números com o Texto em Fontes Classicas?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-font-face

Eu estou usando uma `Font-Face` que tem o estilo tipográfico antigo nos numerais é quero alinha-los com o texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que os números dessa fonte seguem o padrão antigo, onde o algarismo é alinhado com as ascendentes e descendentes da fonte e não na *base-line*

Fonte que estou usando Raleway: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway

Veja como os números dela são alinhados em comparação com o texto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Como faço para alinhas os números com o restante do texto usando CSS ?**

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<span>span 1234567890</span>
<h1>título 1234567890</h1>
```

Comment: Boa pergunta, sempre passo por isso!

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz é chato de mais quando a fonte é assim né! Mas acho que tem propriedade que resolve isso hein!

Comment: Deve haver :D, eu espero que tenha hehe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### O problema das fontes

Como o @hugocsl comentou na sua pergunta, existem algum tipos de fontes onde os números da fonte seguem um padrão antigo, onde o mesmo é alinhado com as ascendentes e descendentes da fonte e não na baseline. Veja:

[image: Anatomia de uma fonte]

Em *text figures* (figuras de texto), os numerais são compostos com alturas variadas que se assemelham a uma linha de texto. Alguns numerais, mais comumente 0, 1 e 2, não têm ascendentes nem descendentes e são de altura x como letras minúsculas, enquanto 6 e 8 têm ascendentes e 3, 4, 5, 7, 9 têm descendentes. Veja com um exemplo para facilitar o entendimento:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<span>span 0123456789</span>
```

Se você analisar bem verá que o 0, 1 e 2 estão alinhados com as letras minúsculas, por sua vez o 6 e o 8 tem ascendentes e o resto dos números descendentes, como dito anteriormente.

Mas o que são ascendentes e descententes?

> Os ascendentes são um traço vertical ascendente encontrado em certas
>   letras minúsculas que se estendem além da "altura da capa" (*cap
>   height*) ou da *baseline*. Descendentes são o traço vertical
>   descendente nessas letras.

Mas isso é realmente um problema, essas fontes que não tem alinhamento na baseline?

Na verdade isso depende muito de cada ponto de vista, pode ser um problema para mim e para você não. Mas eu acredito que isso às vezes tira o padrão de um texto e também pode atrapalhar a leitura de um texto muito grande por distrair a pessoa. **Se você não gostar ou não quiser resolver com CSS pode trocar de fonte ;D**.

### **As soluções :0**

Vamos ao que realmente interessa, a propriedade CSS que faz esse alinhamento a baseline acontecer, a `font-feature-settings`! Uma propriedade capaz de te dar controle sobre tipografia avançada nas fontes do tipo OpenType, como o caso da Raleway. O que nos vamos fazer com a nossa fonte é permitir *lining figures* (não tenho uma tradução para isso), também chamadas de *modern figures*, que tem altura uniforme e que são alinhadas com a *baseline*. Ressalto que a fonte tem *lining figures* mas que por padrão não vem habilitada nos navegadores.

Vale ressaltar que ela é compatível com quase todos os navegadores, mas use os prefixos para dar suporte a versões antigas.

Enfim, veja um exemplo e tire as suas próprias conclusões.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum"; 
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum"; 
  font-feature-settings: "lnum"; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<span>span 0123456789</span>
```

Mas o que é o "lnum" passado a propriedade?

Na verdade essa é uma resposta simples, a mais simples que vou responder aqui. É meio que um sinônimo para *lining figures*. Existem diversos valores que você pode passar para a `font-feature-settings` e "lnum" é só um deles. Nesse link [você](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-feature-settings/) tem uma lista completa e alguns exemplos.

Antes de terminar vou deixar outra solução que encontrei em uma pergunta no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942294/font-messes-up-alignment-of-numbers). Só deixo ela por ser <strike>uma gambiarra</strike> criativa e que pode servir de ajuda ou de solução para algumas pessoas em alguns casos.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $text-color;
  border-top: 1px solid $text-color;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.raised {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 12%;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h1>
  <span class="raised">5</span>
  Comments
</h1>
```

Algumas referências que usei para montar a resposta:

- [Understanding typography](https://material.io/design/typography/understanding-typography.html#)
- [Fixing Raleway and Similar Font's Numerals](https://www.codesmite.com/article/fixing-raleway-and-similar-fonts-numerals)
- [font-feature-settings MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings)
- [Lining Figures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/lining-figures)

Comment: Valeu jovem! Ótima explicação

Comment: Obrigado mano!!

Comment: Pedrão vi essa propriedade que também parece alinhar os número `font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;` veja aqui mais detalhes https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-variant-numeric-prop

Comment: Show mano, não tinha visto essa, mas pela documentação que você passou parece que ela realiza esse alinhamento nos números. Vou testar ela e qualquer coisa incluo na resposta. Obrigado pela observação hehe!